# How can I remove TabBar if I enter one given ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Setting:

Assume I have 2 TableViewControllers(All in their own NavigationControllers), which contain TypeA&B items correspondingly.

In any TableView, If I tap "+" button, it will segue to a Add[?]ItemViewController("?" is The Type of Item: A or B).So normally, even if I already in the AddView, I can also switch to another View By tapping Tab Bar Icon, right?

SO How can I inhibit user to switch if they already entered one AddView?

> Use the **Swift** code? or just change the storyboard structure?

Here is the Structure of Main.storyboard:

[image]

Comment: i have added answer, if its helpful , please upvote it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We've done exactly the same in our application. To hide the default
>   TabBar, simply override the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed method in your
>   parent view controller (or in every view controller in your App)

```
#pragma mark - Overriden UIViewController methods
- (BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
    return YES;
}
```

[image]

## another Solution

**You can also Hide Tab bar**

```
// pass a param to describe the state change, an animated flag and a completion block matching UIView animations completion 
- (void)setTabBarVisible:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL))completion {

    // bail if the current state matches the desired state
    if ([self tabBarIsVisible] == visible) return;

    // get a frame calculation ready
    CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height;
    CGFloat offsetY = (visible)? -height : height;

    // zero duration means no animation
    CGFloat duration = (animated)? 0.3 : 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, 0, offsetY);
    } completion:completion];
}

// know the current state
- (BOOL)tabBarIsVisible {
    return self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame);
}

// illustration of a call to toggle current state
- (IBAction)pressedButton:(id)sender {

    [self setTabBarVisible:![self tabBarIsVisible] animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"finished");
    }];
}
```

## another Solution

**You can set the UIViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed instead:**

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
detailViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```